# Removing rows on column value by ID in R

Tags: r

Apologies if this is posted elsewhere I did searches here and elsewhere and found things that were close but not quite what I needed.  After sinking a couple hours into this, I'm posting!

I need to remove rows from a data set for duplicate values in value1 by id.  So in the following data frame I'd only want to remove row 3.  I do not want to remove row 10 or row 9.  If it makes a difference, in the actual date the values are dates.

I know the solution is probably very simple but I've yet to get it exactly right.  Thanks!

```
x <- data.frame(cbind(id=c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6), value1=c(6,8,8,1,9,5,4,3,8,4), value2=1:10))
> x
    id   value1  value2
 1   1      6      1
 2   2      8      2
 3   2      8      3
 4   2      1      4
 5   3      9      5
 6   3      5      6
 7   4      4      7
 8   5      3      8
 9   6      8      9
 10  6      4     10
```

I want to end up with:

```
> x
    id   value1  value2
 1   1      6      1
 2   2      8      2
 4   2      1      4
 5   3      9      5
 6   3      5      6
 7   4      4      7
 8   5      3      8
 9   6      8      9
 10  6      4     10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `duplicated`:

```
> x[!duplicated(x[1:2]), ]
   id value1 value2
1   1      6      1
2   2      8      2
4   2      1      4
5   3      9      5
6   3      5      6
7   4      4      7
8   5      3      8
9   6      8      9
10  6      4     10
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!  I also just found that x[rownames(unique(x[,-3])),] works, but duplicated is faster.